Stretched space in math mode
I'm wondering why LaTeX occasionally expands spaces in math mode. How can I prevent this from happening? For instance, consider the following example...
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{b{0.35\textwidth}
                    >{\Centering}b{0.3\textwidth}
                    >{\Centering}b{0.3\textwidth}}
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} &
        \textbf{Text} \\
        \toprule
        Text & $x = 1$ & $y = 2$ \\
        \midrule
        Text &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{$z = 3 \text{ mm}$} \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{b{0.35\textwidth}
                    >{\Centering}b{0.3\textwidth}
                    >{\Centering}b{0.3\textwidth}}
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} &
        \textbf{Text} \\
        \toprule
        Text & \mbox{$x = 1$} & \mbox{$y = 2$} \\
        \midrule
        Text &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{$z = 3 \text{ mm}$} \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    
\end{document}

The resulting output is the following:

In the second table, I attempted to use the mbox for all entries. This approach was successful. However, I'm curious about the underlying reason for this behaviour and whether there's a more efficient and straightforward method to achieve the same result. Creating an mbox for each table entry doesn't seem to be the most optimal solution.

You are specifying that white space within short lines should be stretched, by using \Centering (which only adds finite stretch at the margins) rather than the standard \centering. If you don't intend that don't use the ragged2e package versions and use standard \centering

Just out of idle curiosity: Why do you employ the b column type instead of either p or m?

@Mico In some cases I enlarge the row width and I like when the text is just above the rule. From my point of view it is better arranged and more readable.

You are specifying that white space within short lines should be stretched, by using \Centering (which only adds finite stretch at the margins) rather than the standard \centering. If you don't intend that don't use the ragged2e package versions and use standard \centering
alternatively, and preferably if these are one line entries, use c columns, and specify the width using w

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{b{0.32\textwidth}
                    >{\Centering}b{0.28\textwidth}
                    >{\Centering}b{0.28\textwidth}}
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} &
        \textbf{Text} \\
        \toprule
        Text & $x = 1$ & $y = 2$ \\
        \midrule
        Text &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{$z = 3 \text{ mm}$} \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{b{0.32\textwidth}
                    >{\centering\arraybackslash}b{0.28\textwidth}
                    >{\centering\arraybackslash}b{0.28\textwidth}}
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} &
        \textbf{Text} \\
        \toprule
        Text & $x = 1$ & $y = 2$ \\
        \midrule
        Text &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{$z = 3 \text{ mm}$} \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{wl{0.32\textwidth}
                    wc{0.28\textwidth}
                    wc{0.28\textwidth}}
        \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} &
        \textbf{Text} \\
        \toprule
        Text & $x = 1$ & $y = 2$ \\
        \midrule
        Text &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{$z = 3 \text{ mm}$} \\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{3\baselineskip}

\end{document}


A simpler example without math or tables

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

{\Centering x\hspace{1pt plus 1pt}x

}


{\centering x\hspace{1pt plus 1pt}x

}


\end{document}


Thank you for clarity. However during my Latex learninig I found out that in some cases it is necessary to use the following sequence: \raggedright\arraybackslash to reset the definition of \ so that it ends the table row. So in the learning material it has been suggested to use the alternatives from the ragged2e packages (see https://www.learnlatex.org/en/more-08)

@Richard yes I used \arraybackslash with \centering above (that command was my idea originally:-). \Centering avoids that problem but that is far from the only thing it changes....

Ah ok, by the way I just kept using the ragged2e alternatives, since they were shorter compared to "\centering\arraybackslash". I was not aware of this. Thank you.
